# How can I display the sum of all cell's validation errors in a DataGridRow's ControlTemplate but only the cell's errors when hovering the cell?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, tooltip, contenttemplate

I have a DataGrid and I validate the user input for each cell using `IDataErrorInfo`. An appropriate error message is displayed for each cell when the user inputs invalid data. 
How can I collect and display all row's cell error messages when I hover the ValidationErrorTemplate (controltemplate) on the left hand side of the grid's row?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="ArialMT"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,0,0,0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="!" />
                    <!--<ToolTip  {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSourceSelf}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>-->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="true" >-->
        <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Self}}" Value="true" >-->
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
        <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="false" >-->
        <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Self}}" Value="false" >-->
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update 2019-01-25:**
My style defining an erroneous cell:

```
<Style x:Key="textBlockErrStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false" >
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=RawTag.ErrorList, Converter={StaticResource conv:StringToListConverter}}"/>-->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update 2019-02-18:**

This is how the DataGridRow looks like after an invalid character was entered:
[image]

This is how the DataGridRow looks like after all invalid characters were deleted:
[image]

--> The red border is still around the row and the alert sign on the left hand side of the row is still visible.

I tried this as well:

```
    public void RemoveError(string propertyName, bool notify = true)
    {
        if (ErrorList.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            ErrorList.Remove(propertyName);
            HasErrors = ErrorList.Count > 0;
            //NotifyErrorsChanged(propertyName);
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            OnPropertyChanged("GetAllErrors");
        }
        if (notify) ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

...although I use `OnPropertyChange` anyway in each setter of th model class. The error list is empty but the border and the alert symbol stay.

**Update 2019-02-19:**

My implementation of the INotfiyPropertyChanged interface:

```
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler to register for property changed event
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to invoke the property change event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the changed property</param>
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

I display the tool tip like this:

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}"
```

Here is the entire template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" Background="#11FF0000" Opacity="0.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="errorBorder"/>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}" />
        <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="15" Height="15"
                                Margin="-15,0,0,0"
                                StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red" >
            <Ellipse.Stroke>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFA0404" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC9C7C7" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Stroke>
        </Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Text="!" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-10,-1"
                                ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}" TextBlock.LineHeight="15.5"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Looks like this:
[image]

**Edit: Info added per comment**

If you want to display a list of all errors you will need to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface for your class. Then do something like this:

```
public bool HasErrors { get; set; } = false;
public Dictionary<string, string> ErrorList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
public void NotifyErrorsChanged(string PropertyName) { ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(PropertyName)); }

public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (!HasErrors || propertyName == null) return null;
    if (ErrorList.Keys.Contains(propertyName)) return new List<string>() { ErrorList[propertyName] };
    if (propertyName != "GetAllErrors") NotifyPropertyChanged("GetAllErrors");
    return new List<string>();
}

public string GetAllErrors
{
    get
    {
        if (!HasErrors) return null;
        int count = 1;
        var errors= "Errors:";
        foreach (var e in ErrorList)
        {
            errors += "\n" + count++ + ". " + e.Value;
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Then in your RowStyle for the datagrid set the tooltip like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding GetAllErrors}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

You should be able get a tooltip of all the errors by hovering any portion of the row.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I added my own methods to remove errors.

```
public void RemoveError(string PropertyName, bool Notify = true)
{
    if (ErrorList.ContainsKey(PropertyName))
    {
        ErrorList.Remove(PropertyName);
        HasErrors = ErrorList.Count > 0;
    }
    if (Notify) ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
}

public void ClearErrors()
{
    var removalList = new Dictionary<string, string>(ErrorList);
    ErrorList.Clear();
    HasErrors = false;
    foreach (var propertyName in removalList.Keys) ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty good, but it displays the error message at the invalid cell. I want to display the collection of the error messages of each cell of a row when I hover the ControleTemplate. Using your ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}" in the TextBlock element causes my app to display only a red circle without the '!' anymore.

Comment: You might take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832172/inotifydataerrorinfo-get-all-validation-errors

Comment: I added an example to do what you want.

Comment: I am just implementing it to test it. 
LOC 3 in 'GetAllErrors(. . .) should be {NotifyErrorsChanged} instead of {NotifyPropertyChanged}, right!? 
Can I use this 'technique' to give the validation result some kind of severity (INFO, WARNING, ERROR)?

Comment: The GetErrors is the interface method. Since GetAllErrors is a property, it needs a NotifyPropertyChanged, whenever errors change so the tooltip updates.

Comment: HasErrors is simply a property I implemented on my own.

Comment: Got it running. Hovering the erorrTemplate, all errors are listed in the Tooltip. 
Last issue: Hovering an invalid cell only ONE error is displays ALL errors as well although I want to display only the errors for the hovered cell. How can I show only the cell's errors in ints Tooltip? My ErrorList is: Dictionary<string, List<string>> (See my updated question.) So what should the Binding be? Or do I have to use a Converter?

Comment: The ErrorTemplate does NEVER disappear after all errors has been resolved. Is there a gentle way to solve this (without resetting the ItemsSource)?

Comment: :-( Still the row is usrrounden by a red border and the alert image on the left hand side of the row is still visible. After removing the error from ErrorList, neither GetErrors nor GetAllErrors is not invoked anymore when I debug the code.

Comment: You have to notifypropertychanged, when removing the errors.

Comment: Add another line NotifyPropertyChanged("GetAllErrors");

Comment: My OnPropertyChanged IS the NotifiyPropertyChanged():
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }